# call beforeValidate in command object

Tags: grails

I have the following command object

```
class SaleDetailCommand implements Serializable {
  Item item
  Presentation presentation
  String measure
  Integer quantity
  BigDecimal total

  static constraints = {
    importFrom SaleDetail
  }

  def beforeValidate() {
    total = item.sellingPrice * quantity
  }
```

}

in the above command object I am trying to calc total just before command object is validated, but beforeValidate is not call it when i try this code from controller

```
if (command.hasErrors()) {
  command.errors.allErrors.each { error ->
    log.error "[$error.field: $error.defaultMessage]"
  }

  return error()
}
```

I get this message in console

**Error 2014-09-23 08:06:26,585 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] ERROR builder.ActionDelegate  - [total: Property [{0}] of class [{1}] cannot be null]**

I also tried !command.validate

Which is solution to perform this task?

thanks for your time!

Comment: What version of Grails are you using?

Comment: in order to do the job i am setting deafult value to total to pass constraints like this **BigDecimal total = 1** and in controller after check for errors i calculate total **def total = command.item.sellingPrice * command.quantity**, it is working but i would like to implement the right solution